# INSERTing results FROM table USING CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to insert values from a Table using CTE but something doesn't work. I suppose that CTE doesn't work in this way?

Can anyone explain to me what's wrong here and suggest me an alternative, or correct my Query if I'm missing something?

```
WITH t1 AS( SELECT id_sitio as id_sitio FROM Sitio WHERE nombre = 'Insert your site name here')
         INSERT INTO Sitio_tipo_equipo (id_sitio, id_tipo_equipo) 
         VALUES 
            (t1.id_sitio ,4),
            (t1.id_sitio, 6),
            (t1.id_sitio, 7),
            (t1.id_sitio, 9);
```

Comment: To make sure I understand, the end result is you want a Sitio_tipo_equipo  record for all id_sitio and a id_tipo_equipo value of 4,6,7, and 9. Correct?

Comment: @Ghost thats correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is your intention:

```
WITH t1 AS (
      SELECT id_sitio
      FROM Sitio
      WHERE nombre = 'Insert your site name here'
)
INSERT INTO Sitio_tipo_equipo(id_sitio, id_tipo_equipo) 
     SELECT t1.id_sitio, n.n
     FROM t1 CROSS JOIN
          (SELECT 4 as n UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 9
          ) n
```

You wouldn't normally use a CTE with an `insert . . . values` statement.

Comment: You forgot `t1.n` in the `SELECT`

Answer (score 1):

With the information at hand...

```
INSERT INTO Sitio_tipo_equipo (id_sitio, id_tipo_equipo) 
   SELECT id_sitio,eq.id_tipo_equipo
   FROM Sitio
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT 4 [id_tipo_equipo] UNION
      SELECT 6 UNION
      SELECT 7 UNION
      SELECT 9
   ) eq
   WHERE nombre = 'Insert your site name here'
```

What I would do if I can correctly guess your database structure:

```
   INSERT INTO Sitio_tipo_equipo (id_sitio, id_tipo_equipo) 
       SELECT id_sitio,id_tipo_equipo
       FROM Sitio
       CROSS APPLY tipo_equipo
       WHERE nombre = 'Insert your site name here'
       AND id_tipo_equipo IN (4,6,7,9)
```